# Why won't this loop work properly? (Python)

Tags: python, loops

Here's what I'm trying to do:

There are two files that I am comparing.

So there are two files that contains names of mutations and a number, called `aapos`, associated with that mutation.

In file 1, there are `t` number of mutations and in file 2, there are `s` number of mutations.

Now, the mutations in file number 2 have a specific biological signifiance, so what I'm trying to do is see whether the mutation name (called `tagname` in my program) in file 1 is equivalent to the tagname in file 2, and whether the aapos number for that particular mutation falls within the range of aapos1 and aapos2 in file number 2.

If these 2 conditions are met, then the mutation I have in file 1 has a special biological significance, let's call it category 1. Otherwise, it would fall into category 2, which has no biological significance.

In addition, in each of these files, there is a column called `synonymous` and for each mutation in file 1, the synonymous column is assigned a number of 0 or 1.

Now this is what I want to do: For each mutation that belongs to CATEGORY 2, if the `synonymous` column for that mutation is 0, I want the counter `nonsyntwo` to add 1, and if it is 1, then I want the counter `syntwo` to add 1. Essentially, for all the mutations that belong to category 2, I want a count of how many have an assigned value of 0 in the `synonymous` column and how many have an assigned value of 1.

However, when the program runs, I end up getting a number for `nonsyntwo` and `syntwo`, that is much greater than the number of tagnames in the files that I'm using. If I were to change `s` and `t` to 15 for both (there are like thousands of tagnames in each of those files), then I get 94 as a value for `nonsyntwo`.

How is this possible if the program is iterating through 15 tagnames?

```
for x in range(1,s):
    for b in range (1,t):
        if tagname1[x]== tagname2[b]:   
            if int(aapos1[b]) <= int(aapos[x])<= int(aapos2[b]): 
                snps = snps + 1  
            elif int(synonymous[x]) == 0: 
                nonsyntwo = nonsyntwo + 1
            elif int(synonymous[x]) == 1: 
                syntwo = syntwo + 1 
        elif tagname1[x]!= tagname2[b]: 
            if int(synonymous[x]) == 0: 
                nonsyntwo = nonsyntwo + 1
            elif int(synonymous[x]) == 1: 
                syntwo = syntwo + 1
```

Comment: You realize that the code inside `for x in range(1,s): for b in range(1,t): ...` is being run (s-1)\*(t-1) times, not s+t, right?

Comment: Then why is a value of 94 for `nonsyntwo` when `s` and `t` are 15 surprising?

Comment: Perhaps I am interpreting the way my code is supposed to be read by the program to be wrong. My understanding is that for each tagname in file 1, it will iterate through all the tagnames in file 2 and see if they're equal, then if they're equal, it will check if the aapos value for that tagname in file 1 is within the range of aapos1 and aapos2 in file 2. Therefore, it should do this 15 times since I specified a value of 15. Why would I get a value of 94?The value should be less than 15 since not all 15 tagnames in file 1 will meet the criteria I have set in the if-statements.

Comment: Well, there's the `elif tagname1[x] != tagname2[b]` block which runs whenever the current tag names under consideration aren't equal.  Even if `tagname1` and `tagname2` contain the exact same values, and each appears only once, that block will run 182 times.

Comment: Ok, so how would I restructure it to do what I want it to do? Also, if I were to remove the block you mentioned, I still get 24 for nonsyntwo and 25 for syntwo, and 7 for snps. So, it's still not working the way I intended. If you're fully clear on what I am trying to get, would you be able to help me figure out how to fix it ?

Comment: I don't think I'm fully clear on what you're trying to get, and I need to go to sleep now anyway.

Comment: Ok, I have changed my explantation in the question stem, since there aren't enough characters in the comments to explain it.

Comment: How many columns are in your files? You say there are three columns, but then you are talking about "appos1 and appos2". So does the second file have more than three columns? If not, how are you calculating the range.

Comment: @user2905511 Editing the question is always a good idea. The question itself is read by more people than the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand what you're trying to do and when I started naming hypotheticals it got out of hand, but this is your problem:

```
elif tagname1[x]!= tagname2[b]: 
        if int(synonymous[x]) == 0: 
            nonsyntwo = nonsyntwo + 1
        elif int(synonymous[x]) == 1: 
            syntwo = syntwo + 1
```

This runs for every pair `x,b`. This means that it's going to be executed *at minimum* `(s-2)(t-2)` times. I suspect that this isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to state your problem clearly. We shouldn't have to pick through your question just to understand what it is you are dealing with.

I understand the following:

> So there are two files that contains names of mutations and a number,
>   called aapos, associated with that mutation.  [...]
>   In addition, in each of these files, there is a column called 'synonymous' [...]
>   within the range of aapos1 and aapos2 in file number 2

1. You have two files.
2. The first file has three columns: `tagname, appos, synonymous`.
3. The second file has four columns: `tagname, aapos, appos2, synonymous`.

> Now, the mutations in file number 2 have a specific biological
>   signifiance, so what I'm trying to do is see whether the mutation name
>   (called tagname in my program) in file 1 is equivalent to the tagname
>   in file 2, and whether the aapos number for that particular mutation
>   falls within the range of aapos1 and aapos2 in file number 2. [...]
>    If these 2 conditions are met, then the mutation I have in file 1 has a special
>   biological significance, let's call it category 1

1. You want to check for each line in file2, if the first column matches that in file1
2. If it matches, and if the second column is withing the range of the second and third columns in file2, you want to add the line to a collection called category1; otherwise add to another collection called category2.

> in each of these files, there is a column called 'synonymous' and for
>   each mutation in file 1, the synonymous column is assigned a number of
>   0 or 1. Now this is what I want to do: For each mutation that belongs
>   to CATEGORY 2, if the 'synonymous' column for that mutation is 0, I
>   want the counter 'nonsyntwo' to add 1, and if it is 1, then I want the
>   counter 'syntwo' to add 1.

1. Take each item from the `category2` collection, and count the number of 1 and number of 0s.

If this is correct, then the following is what you need (assuming your files are comma separated)

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

with open('file1.txt') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
   file1 = list(reader)

with open('file2.txt') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
   file2 = list(reader)

cat1 = []
cat2 = []

for line in file2:
   for line2 in file1:
      if line[0] == line2[0]:
          if int(line2[1]) <= int(line[1]) <= int(line2[2]):
              cat1.append(line)
          else:
              cat2.append(line)

counter = Counter(line[3] for line in cat2)
nonsyntwo = counter['0']
syntwo = counter['1']
```

Comment: I tried this, but the loop isn't working for some reason. When I try to print cat1 or cat2, it just shows me the blank list as [].

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about the nature of your problem. However, I have these improvement suggestions:

```
aapos = map(int, appos)
aapos1 = map(int, appos1)
aapos2 = map(int, appos2)
synonyms = map(int, synonyms) # or are they already?
for x in range(1,s):
    for b in range (1,t):
        # Here, x and b go from 1 to s resp t.
        # So you are always missing [0] of the array. 
        # Doing
        x, b = x-1, b-1
        # is not very clean, but it helps for now.
        checksyn = True
        if tagname1[x] == tagname2[b]:
            if aapos1[b] <= aapos[x] <= aapos2[b]:
                snps += 1
                checksyn = False
        if checksyn:
            if synonymous[x] == 0: 
                nonsyntwo += 1
            elif synonymous[x] == 1: # if 1 is the only other possible value, an else: would be enough here.
                syntwo += 1
```

Comment: I tried it mate, but I get values of 0 for both syntwo and nonsyntwo. If I type in print checksyn, then I get "True", but for some reason the rest of the if statements aren't working.